# How to build query in Laravel Query Builder "... ANY (ARRAY ['1', '56', '34']::jsonb[]);"

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

How can I build this query in Laravel Query Builder

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE json_field->'tags' @> ANY (ARRAY ['1', '56', '34']::jsonb[]);
```

Laravel have method `DB::whereJsonContains()` but it searches `AND` condition but I need `OR` condition...

```php
DB::table('table')->whereJsonContains('json_field', ['tags' => [1, 56, 36]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [orWhereJsonContains](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereJsonContains)

```
 $tags=[1,56,36];

        $query= DB::table('table')->whereJsonContains('json_field', $tags[0]);

        for($i=1;$i<count($tags);$i++)
        {
            $query=$query->orWhereJsonContains('json_field',$tags[$i]);
        }

        $values=$query->get();
```

Comment: Thakns!
Your answer solves question, I will mark it accepted if I don't get more relevant answer.

I excpected to see some workaround with Expression, or something like this.
Because conditions never so simple, you need more like "is_deleted = false", so to use it I need to use query in query...

Comment: if you get more relevant answer, please share it